# Big Query command line: subsidiary queries

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using bq command line to read data from multiple tables with similar names, and have subsidiary query problem.

Simple example:

```
bq query --append=true --destination_table=xxxxxxxxxxxx:my_table.result 
SELECT udid FROM (TABLE_QUERY(xxxxxxxxxxxx:my_table,'table_id 
CONTAINS "data_2014_05_05"'))
```

When I run that query in the BQ GUI I get the results. However, when I do it from 
the command line I get: "Error evaluating subsidiary query".

In addition, if I test only the subsidiary query from the command line:

```
bq query  "SELECT * FROM xxxxxxxxxxxx:my_table.__TABLES__ 
           WHERE table_id CONTAINS 'data_2014_05_05'"
```

it works fine and I get the tables' info.

So why is there "Error evaluating subsidiary query" in the main query?

Is there a problem with subsidiaries in bq command line?
There is no example whatsoever online or in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove/escape the special characters, such as the quotes, in your query when passing it to the command line tool.

Comment: You are right! I added \"data_2014_05_05\" and it works! Thanks, I never thought of that!